# IOS application published with AIRSDK 3.7 in cs6 Show Blank screen

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I am developing an ios app using adobe air CS6. whenever i publish my application with air sdk 3.2 its working fine but when i publish same application with airsdk 3.7 a blank screen show and nothing happen.
if anyone know what's the reason behind this please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i got my solution and writing the solution may be it will help some one

the actual problem with my application is am using TLFTEXTFIELD and TLFTEXTFIELD directly not supported in air sdk 3.7
so you can remove the tlftext or  use this solution

For Flash CS6, copy this swc: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc

Into my Flash Builder project using these steps: http://interactivesection.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/include_fl_packages_in_flex_builder-1.jpg

and then use this link http://curtismorley.com/2013/03/05/app-used-to-work-with-air-3-2-or-3-4-doesnt-work-with-air-3-5-or-3-6/#comment-241102